# Html.Action asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, html-helper

I am working on a website (Asp.net mvc), where I have multiple partial views. One of the views is user information and then below there are few other views say books by the user, articles in a given book etc. thats how my controller looks like.

```
public class UserController : Controller
{

   public ActionResult UserInfo(long userid)
   {
        var model.User = LoadUser(userId);
        return View(model);
   } 

   public ActionResult Books(long userId)
   {
        var model.User = LoadUser(userId);
        model.Books = LoadBooks(userId);

        return View(model);
   } 

   public ActionResult Articles(long bookId)
   {
        var model.User = LoadUserByBookId(bookId);
        model.Book = LoadBook(bookId);
        model.Articles= LoadArticles(bookId);

        return  View(model);
   } 

}
```

I have created three partial views for UserInfo, Books and Articles and pass data from a given view. Now you can see with each method things go more complex. I was reading about Html.Action helper which can load individual partial views. But as you can see I need to pass some data from Html.Action helper to the methods so it can load data accordingly for example to load userinfo, I will need to pass userId.

How can I achieve this using this or any other better method. Help will be appreciated.

Regards
Parminder

Comment: "public controller UserController"?  That's novel syntax.

Comment: thanks kirk for reminding me.

Comment: Can someone please edit the `Retrun` to `Return` - its hurting my eyes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me the that Lance provides the final step of this solution. Obviously, if `Html.RenderAction` is used as he describes there must be another Controller Action which has already been invoked, since we now Rendering Actions (Partial views) in a larger view.

What I think you need is a ViewModel which needs to be populated in the main controller action

```
public class PageInfo
{
    public long UserId { get; set; }
    public long BookId { get; set; }
}
```

with the main action

```
....
public ActionResult MainAction()
{
     // you probably have some logic here that gets the actual userid and bookid

     PageInfo theModel = new PageInfo(){UserId = 39894, BookId = 3};
     return View(theModel);
}
```

And then in when calling the RenderAction within the `MainAction` page

```
<%: Html.RenderAction("Articles", new { bookId = Model.BookId }) %>
<%: Html.RenderAction("UserInfo", new { userId = Model.UserId }) %>
<%: Html.RenderAction("Books", new { userId = Model.UserId }) %>
```

Comment: This is the full solution, but you might want to think about just adding the UserInfo, Articles, and Books to the Model, and using <%: Html.RenderPartial("UserInfo", Model.UserInfo) %>, etc.  RenderAction() executes the entire MVC pipeline, while RenderPartial() will just execute the view with the model you pass it.

Comment: @Lance - good point, I did not think of that, however, if those Actions are used elsewhere as well i.e. composed within different views, won't this way be better? I'm thinking ajax. RenderPartial expects a model that has already been created by some controller logic.

Comment: Yeah, it depends on how the actions are used.  For loading the articles, user info, and books with ajax, I'd use RenderAction() in the main view and reuse the actions in an ajax call.

Comment: @parminder - an upvote would be nice, if the answer really helped :)

Answer (score 2):

In a view, Html.RenderAction() will execute the controller, and then render it's returned view as a partial.  you can use it like this:

```
<%: Html.RenderAction("Articles", new { bookId = 3 }) %>
```

The first argument, "Articles" is the name of your action method, the second argument is a C# anonymous object.  We create a bookId property and set it to 3.  That will render the Articles view returned from the Articles action method into your current view.  Good luck!

Comment: <%: Html.RenderAction("Articles", new { bookId = Model.bookId }) %>